# PHP вывод многомерного ассоциативного массива

Tags: массивы, php, вывод

У меня есть многомерный ассоциативный массив. Как мне его можно вывести, что бы всё было показано на экране?

Массив примерно такой:

```
$arr[Ханин]=($arr1[Иван]=19);
$arr[Остроух]=($arr1[Ольга]=18);
$arr[Кульбацкая]=($arr1[Любовь]=25) и т.д.

var_dump($arr); выводит вот так: 
array(3) { ["Ханин "]=> string(4) "19 " ["Остроух "]=> string(4) "18 " ["Иван "]=> string(4) "19 " }

print_r($arr); Вот так:
Array ( [Ханин ] => 19 [Остроух ] => 18 [Иван ] => 19 ) array(3) { ["Ханин "]=> string(4) "19 " ["Остроух "]=> string(4) "18 " ["Иван "]=> string(4) "19 " }
```

Можно ли как-то вывести его по типу дерева? Что бы выглядело как-то так:

```
 [Ханин](
           [Иван] => 19)
[Остроух](
           [Ольга] => 18)
[Кульбацкая](
           [Любовь] => 25)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
echo '<pre>';
print_r($array);
echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Не совсем то, но спасибо ;)

Answer (score 3):

Подойдет?

```
function buildtree($in,$pre="array")    {
    if(is_array($in)){
        foreach($in as $key=>$value){
            buildtree($value,$pre.'-'.$key);
        };
    }
    else{
        echo $pre.':'.$in.'<br>';
    };
};
```

Answer (score 1):

Вы можете обернуть результат в тэг **<pre>**, как показанно ниже.

```
echo '<pre>'.print_r($array, true).'</pre>';
```

Answer (score 1):

На самом деле, выводят обе команды всё правильно. Вы просто неправильный инструмент для просмотра используете - браузер.
Браузер, думая что на выходе html успешно съедает все повторные whitespace символы (пробелы, табы, переходы на новые линии...).

Есть много способов решить данную  проблему:

1. Смотреть вывод не в браузере(консоль)
2. Передать не HTMLный Content-Type браузеру. `header('Content-Type:  text/plain');`
3. Сказать браузеру не форматировать контнент.  Обернуть в `<pre>` тег или задать `white-space: pre;` для стиля(css) элемента в который выводиться информация.
4. Установить `xdebug`. Только на dev машине!!! Он очень красиво форматирует вывод функции `var_dump();`

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Форматированный вывод многомерного массива в браузер
 * @param array $arrayToView
 * @param int $tabCount
 * @return string
 * @author mr. Trushman
 */
public static function prettyArrayView(array $arrayToView, int $tabCount = 3): string
{
    function buildTree($arr, $tabCount = 3): string
    {
        static $output = '';
        static $level = 0;

        if (is_array($arr)) {
            $output .= '[<br>';
            $level++;
            foreach ($arr as $key => $value) {
                $output .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level * $tabCount) . "'" . $key . "' => ";
                buildTree($value);
            }
            $level--;
            $output .= str_repeat('&nbsp;', $level * $tabCount)
                . ']' . ($level > 0 ? ',' : ';') . '<br>';
        } else {
            $output .= "'$arr'," . '<br>';
        }

        return $output;
    }

    return '<pre>' . buildTree($arrayToView, $tabCount) . '</pre>';
}
```

Comment: пожалуйста, постарайтесь оставлять чуть более развёрнутые ответы. дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]